# android studio 2 emulator not scaling correctly

Tags: android, emulation, scaling, android-virtual-device

I am using Android Studio 2.2 on Surface Pro 4 which has high DPI QHD resolution. The issue is with emulator. When I launch AVD manager and create an emulator, following is the result. I have tried changing DPI etc, however, it seems that there is some serious scaling issue. 
Interesting thing is that despite the actual display is shrunk to a corner, the touch / input responses are in actual expected place (black area at the botton of the skin for home button etc.)
See the link below for screenshot.

[image: Scaling issue in android emulator]

Any idea how this can be fixed ? Thanks